# gRPC UDP with Deadline

Tags: c++, udp, grpc

I have created a client-server program based on [one of the tests](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/test/core/iomgr/udp_server_test.cc) in the gRPC repo.

The UDP code in gRPC is not built on top of its RPC layer, and so there is no notion of stubs, etc.

My code works, though I've noticed that under just a mild stress, a huge fraction of messages get dropped, and I'm not sure if it's entirely due to the lossy nature of UDP or it's something about my code.

I have two questions:

1. Main question: Is there a gRPC-way to set deadlines for UDP messages? I am familiar with ClientContext and its deadline feature, but I don't know how to use it in a non-TCP RPC-less code. If not, what is the best way to achieve this?
2. Is a drop rate of %50 for a UDP localhost communication sensible?

My code (It's quite long, so just attaching it for reference. My main question doesn't require reading the code):

```cpp
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// grpc headers
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "src/core/lib/iomgr/udp_server.h"
#include "src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_posix.h"
#include "src/core/lib/iomgr/unix_sockets_posix.h"
#include "src/core/lib/iomgr/sockaddr_utils.h"

using namespace std;


int client_port = 6666;
int server_port = 5555;
int num_of_msgs = 1000;


int listening_port;
int remote_port;

int fd;

int received_msgs_cnt = 0;
vector<bool> is_received(num_of_msgs, false);


enum Role {
    CLIENT,
    SERVER
};

struct Request {
    int id;
};

struct Response {
    int id;
};

Role role;

bool udpServerFinished = false;


void sendUdp(const char *hostname, int port, const char* payload, size_t size) {
    auto transferred = write(fd, (void*)payload, size);
    assert(size == transferred);
}


/***************************************
 * UDP Handler class
 * (will be generated by factory class)
 * upon receiving a new message, the Read()
 * function is invoked
 ***************************************/
class UdpHandler : public GrpcUdpHandler {

public:
    UdpHandler(grpc_fd *emfd, void *user_data):
        GrpcUdpHandler(emfd, user_data), emfd_(emfd) {
    }
    virtual ~UdpHandler() {}
    static void startLoop(volatile bool &udpServerFinished) {
        grpc_core::ExecCtx exec_ctx;
        grpc_millis deadline;

        gpr_mu_lock(g_mu);

        while (!udpServerFinished) {
            deadline = grpc_timespec_to_millis_round_up(gpr_time_add(
                    gpr_now(GPR_CLOCK_MONOTONIC),
                    gpr_time_from_millis(10000, GPR_TIMESPAN)));

            grpc_pollset_worker *worker = nullptr;
            GPR_ASSERT(GRPC_LOG_IF_ERROR(
                    "pollset_work", grpc_pollset_work(UdpHandler::g_pollset, &worker, deadline)));

            gpr_mu_unlock(UdpHandler::g_mu);
            grpc_core::ExecCtx::Get()->Flush();
            gpr_mu_lock(UdpHandler::g_mu);

        }
        gpr_mu_unlock(g_mu);
    }

    static grpc_pollset *g_pollset;
    static gpr_mu *g_mu;

public:
    static int g_num_listeners;

protected:
    bool Read() override {
        char read_buffer[512];
        ssize_t byte_count;

        gpr_mu_lock(UdpHandler::g_mu);
        byte_count = recv(grpc_fd_wrapped_fd(emfd()), read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer), 0);

        processIncomingMsg((void*)read_buffer, byte_count);

        GPR_ASSERT(GRPC_LOG_IF_ERROR("pollset_kick",
                grpc_pollset_kick(UdpHandler::g_pollset, nullptr)));
        gpr_mu_unlock(UdpHandler::g_mu);
        return false;
    }

    void processIncomingMsg(void* msg, ssize_t size) {
        received_msgs_cnt++;
        (void)size;
        int id;
        if (role == Role::CLIENT) {
            Response res;
            assert(size == sizeof(Response));
            memcpy((void*)&res, (void*)msg, size);
            id = res.id;
            cout << "Msg: response for request " << res.id  << endl;
        }
        else {
            Request req;
            assert(size == sizeof(Request));
            memcpy((void*)&req, (void*)msg, size);
            id = req.id;
            cout << "Msg: request " << req.id << endl;

            // send response
            Response res;
            res.id = req.id;
            sendUdp("127.0.0.1", remote_port, (const char*)&res, sizeof(Response));
        }

        // check for termination condition (both for client and server)
        if (received_msgs_cnt == num_of_msgs) {
            cout << "This is the last msg" << endl;
            udpServerFinished = true;
        }

        // mark the id of the current message
        is_received[id] = true;

        // if this was the last message, print the missing msg ids
        if (id == num_of_msgs - 1) {
            cout << "missing ids: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < num_of_msgs; i++) {
                if (is_received[i] == false)
                    cout << i << ", ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << "% of missing messages: "
                    << 1.0 - ((double)received_msgs_cnt / num_of_msgs) << endl;
        }
    }
    void OnCanWrite(void* /*user_data*/, grpc_closure* /*notify_on_write_closure*/) override {
        gpr_mu_lock(g_mu);

        GPR_ASSERT(GRPC_LOG_IF_ERROR("pollset_kick",
                grpc_pollset_kick(UdpHandler::g_pollset, nullptr)));
        gpr_mu_unlock(g_mu);
    }
    void OnFdAboutToOrphan(grpc_closure *orphan_fd_closure, void* /*user_data*/) override {
        grpc_core::ExecCtx::Run(DEBUG_LOCATION, orphan_fd_closure, GRPC_ERROR_NONE);
    }

    grpc_fd *emfd() { return emfd_; }

private:
    grpc_fd *emfd_;
};


int UdpHandler::g_num_listeners = 1;

grpc_pollset *UdpHandler::g_pollset;
gpr_mu *UdpHandler::g_mu;



/****************************************
 * Factory class (generated UDP handler)
 ****************************************/
class UdpHandlerFactory : public GrpcUdpHandlerFactory {
public:
    GrpcUdpHandler *CreateUdpHandler(grpc_fd *emfd, void *user_data) override {
        UdpHandler *handler = new UdpHandler(emfd, user_data);
        return handler;
    }

    void DestroyUdpHandler(GrpcUdpHandler *handler) override {
        delete reinterpret_cast<UdpHandler *>(handler);
    }
};




/****************************************
 * Main function
 ****************************************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        cerr << "Usage: './run client'  or  './run server' " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string r(argv[1]);
    if (r == "client") {
        cout << "Client is initializing to send requests!" << endl;
        role = Role::CLIENT;
        listening_port = client_port;
        remote_port = server_port;
    }
    else if (r == "server") {
        cout << "Server is initializing to accept requests!" << endl;
        role = Role::SERVER;
        listening_port = server_port;
        remote_port = client_port;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "Usage: './run client'  or  './run server' " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /********************************************************
     * Initialize UDP Listener
     ********************************************************/
    /* Initialize the grpc library. After it's called,
     * a matching invocation to grpc_shutdown() is expected. */
    grpc_init();

    grpc_core::ExecCtx exec_ctx;
    UdpHandler::g_pollset = static_cast<grpc_pollset *>(
            gpr_zalloc(grpc_pollset_size()));
    grpc_pollset_init(UdpHandler::g_pollset, &UdpHandler::g_mu);

    grpc_resolved_address resolved_addr;
    struct sockaddr_storage *addr =
            reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_storage *>(resolved_addr.addr);
    int svrfd;

    grpc_udp_server *s = grpc_udp_server_create(nullptr);
    grpc_pollset *pollsets[1];

    memset(&resolved_addr, 0, sizeof(resolved_addr));
    resolved_addr.len = static_cast<socklen_t>(sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
    addr->ss_family = AF_INET;

    grpc_sockaddr_set_port(&resolved_addr, listening_port);

    /* setup UDP server */
    UdpHandlerFactory handlerFactory;

    int rcv_buf_size = 1024;
    int snd_buf_size = 1024;

    GPR_ASSERT(grpc_udp_server_add_port(s, &resolved_addr, rcv_buf_size,
            snd_buf_size, &handlerFactory,
            UdpHandler::g_num_listeners) > 0);

    svrfd = grpc_udp_server_get_fd(s, 0);
    GPR_ASSERT(svrfd >= 0);
    GPR_ASSERT(getsockname(svrfd, (struct sockaddr *) addr,
            (socklen_t *) &resolved_addr.len) == 0);
    GPR_ASSERT(resolved_addr.len <= sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));

    pollsets[0] = UdpHandler::g_pollset;
    grpc_udp_server_start(s, pollsets, 1, nullptr);

    string addr_str = grpc_sockaddr_to_string(&resolved_addr, 1);
    cout << "UDP Server listening on: " << addr_str << endl;
    thread udpPollerThread(
            UdpHandler::startLoop, ref(udpServerFinished));



    /********************************************************
     * Establish connection to the other side
     ********************************************************/
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *) server->h_addr,
            (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
            server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(remote_port);

    fd = socket(serv_addr.sin_family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    GPR_ASSERT(fd >= 0);
    GPR_ASSERT(connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == 0);


    /********************************************************
     * Send requests
     ********************************************************/
    if (role == Role::CLIENT) {
        static int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_msgs; i++) {
            Request req;
            req.id = counter++;
            cout << "Sending request " << req.id << endl;
            sendUdp("127.0.0.1", remote_port, (char*)&req, sizeof(Request));
        }
    }

    /********************************************************
     * wait for client to finish
     ********************************************************/
    udpPollerThread.join();

    /********************************************************
     * cleanup
     ********************************************************/
    close(fd);
    gpr_free(UdpHandler::g_pollset);
    grpc_shutdown();

    cout << "finished successfully!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:
`-std=c++17 -I$(GRPC_DIR) -I$(GRPC_DIR)/third_party/abseil-cpp`.
Linked with:
`pkg-config --libs grpc++`